# Can you change the format of dynamic partitions of Hive tables?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

**PRELUDE**

I'm using an external Hive table with dynamic partitioning.

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict
```

The table looks something likt this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `some_test`(
  `id` bigint, 
  `timestamp` int, 
  `some_other_values` bigint)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` int, 
  `month` int, 
  `day` int, 
  `hour` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://nameservice1/user/Sh4pe/hive-test'
```

Now, I'm inserting via a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` query like this:

```
INSERT INTO `dnies_click_log` 
PARTITION(year, month, day, hour) 
SELECT * FROM `other_db`.`other_table` 
WHERE year=2016 and month=4 and day=1 and hour=0 
LIMIT 1;
```

The insert works, I'm actually generating an entry in the table and of course a file in HDFS.

**MY QUESTION**

But I'm not quite satisfied by the way the directories in HDFS are stored:

```
Sh4pe:/home/Sh4pe$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/Sh4pe/hive-test/
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs dnies          0 2016-04-05 14:33 /user/Sh4pe/hive-test/some_test/year=2016
```

What bothers me is the `year=2016` part. I'd like to have `2016` instead. Similarly, the nested folder is called `month=4`. I'd like to have `04` (trailing zero) instead. I'd also prefer the nested day and hour directories to be named only with numbers too.

*Is it possible to change the format in which the dynamic partitions are stored on HDFS?*

Comment: good question, but at the moment i don't think it is possible to change it dynamically. I think the best you could do would be to run some HDFS commands which would rename all the partitions afterwards, which may affect how the external table reads the data.

Comment: Dinamically with an insert not, you could create a new partition or alter a partition to change its location:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionLocation

Answer (score 0):

No possible to have customised directory name for dynamically created partitions. The naming pattern is hard coded in the function org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.FileUtils.makePartName().
https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/c08490b74a15ce57a140c7826ad4c666f8be719e/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/common/FileUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth looking at these links:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+DynamicPartitions#HCatalogDynamicPartitions-HiveDynamicPartitions

and

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6109

Looks like they started catering for custom names since Hive 0.13.0.  E.g.

```
set hcat.dynamic.partitioning.custom.pattern="${year}/${month}/${day}";
```